# Windows 7 SYSTEM cmd possibility?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, administrator

I have an access to system cmd (the one before you login to domain) and a non admin user located on domain. Since SYSTEM user is considered a higher privilege than admin in windows 7, how do I move one of my domain users to admin privilege on the same domain. I know that using:
net localgroup administrators username /add
will make this account an admin only locally on computer, usually even without connecting it to the network, which is completely useless
help me with syntax or give an example of how to promote an already existing domain user to domain admin while having SYSTEM cmd available

Comment: You can't control permissions on the domain unless you're logged into the domain. "SYSTEM" isn't a domain user.  If you had proper permissions and were logged into the domain properly, you could use `net group`.

Answer (score 1):

You managed to be a local administrator on that machine, which means you can only manage that particular machine. In order to make changes to the domain, you actually need to manage the domain.

Such is being done through Active Directory Users and Computers. Using this either on the domain controller, or from your own computer and then connecting to the domain controller, can only be done using a user that has enough privileges to do this, such as a membership of Network Administrator or Administrators group.

The only thing you can do with this, is grant a non-admin user local admin to this computer, or perform any other admin tasks on this computer.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I add user to a domain using local admin cmd

You cannot.  Only Domain accounts can add accounts to the domain.

Comment: Only domain accounts *with the correct permissions to add accounts*, that is.

Comment: I've lost the domain account details. Is there any way to get them back or do I have to purchase whole new domain?? All PCs are windows 7 btw and I have access to local admin

Comment: thats not good..   what version of windows server are you running?

Comment: `I have to purchase whole new domain??` - Uhm, what?  I am going to need more information about how you got this 'domain' in the first place to answer that.

Comment: this chinese guy was selling wires and said i can create my own internet with those just for $40 so i bought them and now i dont have domain admin and for some reason chinese guy not there anymore, pls help find domain admin

Comment: "this chinese guy was selling wires and said i can create my own internet with those just for $40 so i bought them and now i dont have domain admin and for some reason chinese guy not there anymore, pls help find domain admin"  WHAT!? I'm beginning to think you're trolling us.

Comment: We can only hope he is trolling us :)   that story is too crazy to believe.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add an account to the Domain Controller with administrative rights (or use the built in Administrator account on your Windows Server, not recommended though).

To create a new account in AD that you can use to add computers to the domain, do the following:

1. Log on as a member of the Domain Admins group, and then open Active Directory Users and Computers.
2. Right-click the Users container, click New, and then click User.
   Active Directory Users and Computers

[image]

3. Type the First name, Last name, and User logon name, and then click
   Next.

[image]

4. Type and confirm the user password, clear the User must change password at next logon check box, and then click Next.

[image]

5. Review the account information and then click Finish.

[image]

6. With the Users container selected, in the details pane (right pane),
   double-click the Domain Admins group.
7. Click the Members tab.

[image]

8. Click Add and then, in the Select Users, Contacts, or Computers
   dialog box, type the user logon name of the administrative account
   you just created, and then click OK.

[image]

9. Verify that your new account appears as a member of the Domain
   Admins group.

[image]

Further info is available at

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc700835.aspx